# Why do some higher reputation users feel the need to bully other users?

Tags: discussion, reputation, downvotes

I have been a member of Stack Overflow for the past four years. I have made it through a lot of bullying from higher reputation users during this period.

For the sake of discussion, consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441993/preferred-tostring-implementation/30442028#30442028). The first comment on the answer reads:

> This is nonsense. The compiler will optimise the first case into a
>   single StringBuilder. –  Boris the Spider

I am wondering if the same wording would have been used if I had a rating higher than that of the user who posted this comment? I chose to ignore the rude comment and replied as follows:

> @BoristheSpider and Luiggi: My answer is based on my personal
>   experience. I have come across this issue twice on JDK 1.7 in the past
>   one year so if you have a solid source that can say that the compiler
>   will always optimize the first case, please point me to it

So far so good. No harm done. The next comment is where I believe the higher reputation of the user allowed them to believe that they could be sarcastic:

> How's the JLS‌​? To increase the performance of repeated string
>   concatenation, a Java compiler may use the StringBuffer class or a
>   similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate String objects
>   that are created by evaluation of an expression. –  Boris the Spider

The part *"How's the JLS"* is clearly a sarcastic comment intended to make fun of my request of asking for a solid source.

I replied to the above comment as follows:

> @BoristheSpider Please see this. What does may mean. Then read the JLS again. The point I am making is that the JLS says may and not always. I specifically emphasized on the word always in my comment but you did not get the point. –  Chetan Kinger

After this comment, I did not get any reply from the user.

Now if something like this was a one-off, I would have ignored this. Although, this has happened way too many times to me. I have flagged so many rude and offensive comments that I am tired of it. Yesterday, I flagged a comment *from a moderator* as rude or offensive; it was marked as a helpful flag. This goes a long way to say that there is something really wrong at the core of this site.

Higher reputation users get away by saying something cheesy to make lower reputation users look like fools. Such behavior has become an integral part of Stack Overflow.

Why do some higher reputation users feel the need to bully other users?  The funny part is that this bullying spreads like a disease and users like me who have been through it end up bullying other new users without even noticing. Is this the culture the Stack Overflow community wishes to have on their site?

One does not analyze a statement and decide whether they should get offended by it or not. Getting offended by something is a natural impulse. Even though I was offended by `This is nonsense`, I did give the user the benefit of the doubt and responded sincerely to this comment. The above post is one incident that you have the luxury to scrutinize word by word. I request users not to focus their answers on the specific incident. Instead, if you can focus your answers on the broader issue in general, it would be really helpful to many users who face similar behavior regularly on this site. I did not keep a track of previous incidences of this nature. If anyone else feels that they have come across similar incidents, feel free to edit my question and point out the incident. I did not come here to ask whether I am wrong to be offended in this particular case. I came here to point out a bigger problem at the core of the community and ask the community to take efforts to cultivate a positive culture on the site. Stricter moderation rules that allow this would really be helpful. (High rep users play a very important role in shaping the community).

In an effort to get my point across, I will be posting links to incidents support my observations:

**[A user comments: `Do you think I am daft?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504714/java-lang-charsequence-cannot-be-resolved-in-jdk-1-8/30504775?noredirect=1#comment49085131_30504775)**

First comment form me:

> Did you mean to post this as a comment? –  Chetan Kinger

Comment from the user:

> Nope - I posted it as an answer. Do you think I'm daft? –  duffymo

Comment from me:

> I don't think you are daft. I feel that external links make a good
>   recipe for comments. Links can expire so answers should be self
>   explanatory. – Chetan Kinger

User deletes their post. (I believe moderators and users with higher reputation can see deleted posts). Once again, a user with a high reputation thought that they somehow had the right to speak to me this way because they have a higher reputation than me. This incident is exactly the opposite of the main incident posted as part of my question. In this particular incident, I was the one questioning the validity of the answer and was again at the receiving end of an unwarranted reply.

Comment: Is JLS a Java thingie?

Comment: This question is asking why users do this. Not how to handle it.

Comment: Why do you assume that reputation has something to do with it?

Comment: I've never experienced the kind of proud bullies as I have in the Java community, in SO and out. Its really unfortunate.

Answer (score 24):

I see this as nothing more than another person (with potentially more experience in Java than yourself) disagreeing with your stance.

While I'd be tempted to close the question as being too opinionated (readability is subjective, performance matters only if you can successfully follow [Rule #2 of Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization)), there is some truth being said about why your stance isn't correct from a performance standpoint, and there are links in the comments to back this up.  If you could provide links/references to back up *your* stance, then it wouldn't be such a big thing.

I legitimately do not see any bullying here; just disagreement.  Disagreeing is a natural thing that happens both here and in the industry.  I wouldn't let this one get to you; if you could further back up your stance with sources then you'd have the logical upper hand in your viewpoint.

Comment: I feel that `This is nonsense` and `How's the JLS` are both rude. Can you elaborate why a better choice of words such as `That's not true` or `See the JLS` is not a better option? As far as the links in the answer go, I already responded to the links and explained why the links cant be trusted. Last but not the least, even if I did back my stance (which I can since I have faced the issue twice), such replies would still be called rude. If one came cross such replies often, it could be termed as bullying.

Comment: I'd consider that choice of words more "heated" as opposed to "rude".  While statements such as "This is nonsense" and "How's the JLS?" are generally abrasive, there's nothing in there that in which you are directly being insulted.  This is why I don't feel like it's rude.

Comment: Rudeness can be subjective. What's rude to you may not be rude to me. Keeping the issue of whether the comment was rude or not aside, I strongly believe that higher rep users have a bigger role to play in shaping the community.

Comment: Rudeness is a function of etiquette, @ChetanKinger, and etiquette is a product of _society_. You don't get to decide on your own what's rude and what isn't. You can be _offended_ by whatever you choose, but the flipside is that you don't get to tell other people that they can't offend you.

Comment: @ChetanKinger: attacking the answer is OK while an [ad hominem attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem) is not. The attack on the answer may be aggressive if the person making the comment is vehemently opposed to the answer, and that's what I'm seeing here. And your question has nothing to do with "hi rep" and such but more to do with degree of disagreement.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I was not the one who started the ad hominem attack. My response to the first comment (This is nonsense) was a sincere one. The next comment from the user was `How's the JLS` and he continued the comment by quoting the JLS without even actually reading it carefully. This goes to show that the intention of the user was not only to voice their disagreement but to also make me look like a fool. My response to this comment was just an attempt to make the user stop the unwarranted behavior .

Comment: What the heck is "JLS"?

Comment: @Braiam:  [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).

Comment: That explains some stuff... When I searched for it I got this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JLS nothing on my first page says "Java".

Answer (score 21):

None of the comments pointed to here are what I would call rude.

Questioning the validity of an answer does not make someone a bully.

I'm new here, but so far as a "low rep." user my experience has been pretty good. No one has made any inappropriate comments. No one has "Bullied" me.

However I do see a lot of times where more experienced users point out potential flaws in someone's work. Often times these comments are a little terse, but they usually aren't rude.
"You're doing it wrong..." isn't rude, it's short and pointed, but not rude.

Honestly, the few times that I have seen users "bullying" or being rude, have more often been low rep users being rude to lower rep users. As in a person with 500 rep picking on someone with 200 or 300 rep. Sort of a "Stupid N00B you don't already know the thing I just learned about yesterday..."

Comment: `This is nonsense` as a first comment on an answer without giving someone the benefit of the doubt is rude IMO.

Comment: @ChetanKinger: You are entitled to your opinion, as long as you keep in mind that acting on it, pushing it and expecting others to share it might not be appropriate. Because while a comment only consisting of "this is nonsense" *would* be rude and non-constructive, as it's followed up by the details it's just a short and blunt summary as an introduction.

Comment: @Deduplicator 
I have edited my question. I hope you will appreciate the fact that this is just one of the many incidences I have come across. I don't want this particular incident to be scrutinized but the broader problem to be solved instead

Comment: `Questioning the validity of an answer does not make someone a bully` I have edited my question with an incident where I questioned the validity of an answer and the user responded with an unwarranted reply.

Comment: @ChetanKinger I think you may be taking things a little too personally, "Do you think I'm daft?" isn't very strong language. It may have been "unwarranted", but in that context I wouldn't have found it offensive.

Comment: @SarahJane Never ever have I come across any user with a lower reputation than me who has felt the need to talk this way. How is `Do you think I am daft` not offensive? The only situation where such a statement would not be offensive is when said in a playful way. (And I don't think it was said in a playful way in this particular case). In any other situation, it can only be spoken with a lot of hate.

Comment: @CKing never ascribe to malice what can be explained by ineptitude (yours or theirs).  Text is a very difficult medium for communication especially for the finer points.  Given those two things I don't see how `Do you think I am daft` could be construed as anything other than a bit of a cry for help, especially if it was only part of the comment in question.

Answer (score 15):

First off, the important factor of bullying is the relative power levels of the two parties. Without a *stronger* party trying to intimidate and influence the behavior of the other, you have, at worst, rudeness.

Where's the power imbalance in a comment on Stack Overflow? Nothing about the commenter's rep score has an impact on the mechanics of the comment: Jon Skeet's comment is presented like any other user's. The score isn't even displayed the way it is for a question or answer. The comment is a statement with a name attached. The commenter also has no power over your response, other than -- again -- that which any other user would have: to *anonymously* flag or upvote.

For the question of rudeness, I believe that your perception is mistaken.

> This is nonsense. <and here's why>

is a factual statement.* You're free to be offended by someone telling you that you're wrong, of course, even if they back it up. But it would likely be better if you didn't assume that this neutral statement, which contains no personal language, is *intended* to offend. Instead, maybe the commenter is trying to fix a post on a site where answers are supposed be helpful,  correct documents about programming.

Finally, if one user is following you around telling you you're wrong all the time, that person is harassing you and you should raise a flag to alert the moderators of their behavior.

If everyone you meet is telling you you're wrong, including a moderator -- and moderators are held to a high standard of behavior on this site** -- then you should stop and consider the possibility that, at the very least, you don't understand what's going on. There is probably not a mob here that's trying to hurt you personally.

---

*Though it may very well be incorrect, just as it asserts that *your* factual statement is.

**Although I'm sure they make mistakes just like everyone else.

Comment: I have edited my question. I hope you will appreciate the fact that this is just one of the many incidences I have come across. I don't want this particular incident to be scrutinized but the broader problem to be solved instead.

Comment: @chetankinger fair enough, but on meta we usually ask for proof of such claims.  I don't know why some users bully others... it's the internet being the internet. But since we ask for proof in such statements, yes we will analyse said proof.maybe not the best system.  I say we would need to ask a mod to post numbers of rude comments flagged by rep of the commenter to see.... and I'm not sure they will post said numbers

Answer (score -20):

Keep in mind that if they are bullying, they are not answering the questions. This means that their reputation will not grow and most likely decrease if their behavior continues. Flag them and report them, and eventually they will lose the privileges which caused this in the first place.

However, you should not judge someone based on privileges. They can be the type of person who is mean no matter what.

Comment: ...Your reputation only decreases (from a numerical standpoint) if you're downvoted or suspended (the latter being temporary).  So I'm not entirely sure what it is you're getting at with this remark here.

Comment: All I am saying is that if Chetan's argument is correct, many others will share his thoughts. If they do, then someone with higher than 50 or so reputation will downvote bullies around the site, especially him if they see it. 

One more thing, you talked about how "This is nonsense" was not a bullying comment. If an argument was already going on, then the comment would simply be a retort. But why did the user feel the need to say it when Chetan had simply answered based on his own thoughts? The bully struck first, and I strongly believe that is not acceptable

Comment: You're *really* not supposed to use your votes for that purpose (and if there's a pattern detected by the system, it **will** be rolled back and the users who did it would likely be chided).  In situations like this, flag for a moderator attention or bring it up on Meta.  Resorting to silly attacks against a person's reputation will only hurt the attackers (and change *nothing* about the person's alleged behavior).

Comment: @ytpillai I agree with you. `This is nonsense` in the middle of an argument is not rude. If it's the first comment on an answer, it's pretty rude.

Comment: Actually, what you say makes sense Makoto. But that is only applicable if moderators DO something about it

Comment: @ytpillai Well if the moderator looks into it, realizes there's nothing to be done, and decides not to do anything... I mean, you can send something up asking them to look it up and act accordingly. You can't send something up and DEMAND it be deleted... If you send something up and mods don't act on it... chances are that you got offended for nothing, no?

Comment: @Patrice, Look, I have not faced the ordeals that Chetan is talking about. However, not every site is perfect and will have some inappropriate behavior. It is not a moderator's job to judge whether a person should be butt-hurt (for lack of a better term) by a comment or not. His job is to decide whether the comment disobeys StackOverflow rules. I do not believe starting a fight by acting superior for no reason is within them.

Comment: @ytpillai definitely with you on that. But the "ordeal" Chetan is talking about is someone stating "this is nonsense" then proceeding to explaining what's wrong. You can't send that up to the mods and expect them to not question if it REALLY is rude or not.

Comment: @Patrice I don't think you REALLY understood what ytpillai said. The point that you misssed is that a first comment as `This is nonsense` is uncalled for. One should always give someone the benefit of the doubt. Only when one feels that they are better than someone else is when they will not give someone the benefit of the doubt. That is what is wrong in this case. That is what happens a lot on this site. That is the ordeal ytpillai is talking about.

Comment: @ChetanKinger I understood that. And, as most people here are mentionning, "This is nonsense" is not rude in and out of itself. Blunt, yes. Uncalled for? not necessarily. If what you said doesn't make sense, why is it rude to call it out?

Comment: It's not rude to call it out. It's rude to call it out in that manner, especially when you see someone with a lower rep and feel the need to call it out in that manner. A simple `That's not true` would have sufficed.

Comment: @ChetanKinger we're not supposed to look at people but at their posts, so don't assume it was because of rep. "that's not true" to me, is pretty much the same as "that's nonsense". Then again, I have a very thick skin for these kinda things.

Comment: @ChetanKinger Look, what's over is over. The guy is a brat and we all know that. Just carry on with your life and simply ignore him if he comments again :)

Comment: Ironic that on a post about bullying I get 19 downvotes for an admittedly very naive but heartfelt answer.  I was even responsive and got some support from you guys, but people followed the bandwagon without thinking. THIS is the real problem.