# Dyslexic newbies in danger of serious downvotes

Tags: discussion, downvotes, accessibility

Dyslexic coders are already at a disadvantage, seeing things that are not actually there in the code, or reading the code in ways that make it at first sight mean something other than what it means.

Then we find Stack Overflow, and we post our questions, and are treated to assaulting responses. Then we eventually realize, yeah, sure, if you've been doing this forever and you're not learning it for the first time, and you're not dyslexic, maybe it was a dumb question. But no question is dumb that you don't know the answer to.

Dyslexia is a different way of seeing things. It's also a real disability. People who are dyslexic are prone at times to posting what might be perceived by others as dumb questions. Would you downvote someone for having a disability you could see, that was the cause of what you thought was a dumb post?

Many designers and art directors are dyslexic to some degree, but would you create an environment where they were not welcome to ask questions in their own way?

I wonder what kind of features could be developed that would assist in this situation and assist posters with dyslexia in getting their questions answered in a kind way? Someone below in the comments suggested a [dyslexic] tag - I think that's a great idea!

Comment: No! Simple dyslexic failures would be edited out quickly,  if the question is valid in itself. We're not such morons. Well, wording like `plz`, `u` and such alike isn't dyslexia, but laziness and disrespect. (My daughter's a highly intelligent dyslexic, I well know what I'm talking about).

Comment: What matters most is 1) that the poster has read and understands the rules of this site and makes an attempt to follow them. 2) that they put effort into trying to solve their question before coming here and show the results of that effort as part of their question, 3) that they strive to ask a complete and intelligent question. If they do this, dyslexic or not, the question should get a good response and up-votes.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ , That's simply not the case. I've posted a number of questions now that in retrospect seem to have arisen through a dyslexic vision of the world - of the specific coding problem - so, while the text of the question might be written well, it does not mean that the underlying question did not arise from a dyslexic mis reading of the issue - this is not 'caught or edited out' - it's usually treated super harshly.

Comment: So what, we should have a [tag:dyslexic] tag that dyslexics use to alert us to the problems you describe above? No, the question should stand alone on its own merits.

Comment: Can you post to the question or questions that spurred this post?

Comment: Mat, isn't your comment just a tag pedantic? Or am I taking it the wrong way?

Comment: @AgentZebra _"hat in retrospect seem to have arisen through a dyslexic vision of the world"_ So you're a dyslexic and misread, or do you claim others to be so?

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ - I am talking about myself.

Comment: To be a successful programmer you have to be pedantic since compilers are non-forgiving.

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels - yes, great idea, a dyslexic tag. Just as you have ramps for people in wheelchairs to accommodate their needs.

Comment: @AgentZebra My colleage sitting in front of me, is a dyslexic. He's a very successful programmer. I can get over these little errors he leaves in documentation or variable namings most of the time. He's well with me, when I'm pointing out such getting a bigger problem, and he should fix it. So what, actually? To get to the point: Dyslexia, small spelling errors and such won't lead to get questions downvoted normally. Intelligent people are capable to come over these minor defects, and get the essence if it actually is there.

Comment: LindaJeanne, sure, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445384/javascript-why-am-i-getting-an-error-with-throw-new-error?noredirect=1#comment48973007_30445384

and here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420291/node-js-express-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ - dyslexia shows up differently for different people. For some it's more a perception and information ordering issue than a spelling issue, they just see things in a different way.

Comment: So, what would a dyslexia tag mean? "give me special accommodations, but don't help me improve my questions"? I'm unclear on this.

Comment: . –  Hovercraft Full Of Eels - I think it could mean ' be sensitive to this poster and his question' because that's exactly what someone who is dyslexic needs. By all means try to make the question better.

Comment: @AgentZebra: and so in converse we should just roughly roll over those whose questions don't have the tag? No, it would add no benefit to the question, the questioner or the site. Please read this for a similar tag, [the newbie tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60852/why-is-the-newbie-tag-not-allowed).

Comment: –  Chris Hayes it requests a feature that has specifically arisen in these comments and is now added to the original post as a request.

Comment: @AgentZebra Sorry eyrolling, you're arguing the same way my daughter does, when caught in a failure. She's likely to excuse with her dyslexia. That's part of the problem, and why I denied getting that proved over a longer time. All in all the approval is getting her further, and less frustrated in school now, but she still sometimes tends to taht point excusing everything with this. That's where I'm going to decline and disagree.

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels - that's like saying nations that accommodate wheelchairs should rip up the ramps!

Comment: The example questions you linked don't appear to have anything at all to do with dyslexia. They're both fundamental misunderstandings. No offense, but your complaints appear to be caused by a complete lack of familiarity with how Stack Overflow works, and oversensitivity to receiving even a *single downvote* in the case of the second question.

Comment: `"that's like saying nations that accommodate wheelchairs should rip up the ramps!"` -- it's nothing of the kind, and please don't throw Straw Man Fallacies on us.

Comment: –  πάντα ῥεῖ eyeroll away. Dyslexia is a real issue that has real educational and learning consequences and can be scientifically tested for. So, do you want to be compassionate towards those with disabilities or not? You have a right to eyeroll if you prefer, but I think both myself and your daughter would prefer your understanding.

Comment: Voting for any other purpose than the quality of the post is a misuse of the voting system.  We don't vote on people.  We vote on *content*.  Dyslexia plays zero part in voting, and should **absolutely** stay that way.

Comment: –  Chris Hayes - No, the fundamental misunderstanding is PRECISELY the dyslexic aspect of those posts. You do not have a full understanding of the scope of dyslexia. it;s not always about spelling, it's often about the way people order information and see a particular issue. just as b's, p's, q's etc can be turned around in a persons mind, so can simple pieces of code.

Comment: We can't accommodate every single question that comes from somebody misunderstanding something. Can you not see how that doesn't scale at all? Yes, you have dyslexia and that sucks, but that doesn't mean you have the right to ask any question you want here and expect a good reception.

Comment: fbueckert I completely disagree and think that is discriminatory.

Comment: Chris Hayes, I'm sure the same argument was put forward about not having wheelchair ramps before (many parts of) the world finally acquiesced to accommodating the needs of people with disabilities that can be seen.

Comment: @AgentZebra The *entire* voting system is predicated on that simple premise: Vote on the content.  That's it, that's all.  What you're suggesting is a massive shift of the current system, and encourages a user-first mentality.  That's going to kill SO as we know it.  So, no.  It's not discriminatory in the least.  If anything, it's **utterly** indiscriminate.  Nobody gets special treatment.  Everything is just on it's own merits.  And that's what attracts, and keeps, the people the site is built around: the experts.

Comment: If you want to reply to someone, please use `@their-username`. They won't get a notification otherwise.

Comment: How the fsck is voting without consideration of the person "_discriminatory_"? That is an absolute perversion of the word.

Comment: –  fbueckert The same could be said for stairs, but we now have ramps to accommodate those who have a hard time walking up them, and to provide a ramp is seen as the right thing to do.

Comment: Nice strawman there.  The point is, you're using dyslexia as an excuse.  We vote on content, and I absolutely disagree we should change it.

Comment: –  fbueckert Where's the strawman?

Comment: What's the Stack Overflow analog to the ramp?

Comment: @AgentZebra The strawman is how you're using the ramps and stairs. On this site, 100% of the time we don't care who's posting, and we **only judge content**. In your example, less than 100% of the world has ramps + stairs (Therefore not equivalent). The proper analogy is to point out that while other sites may provide "special help" as per your requirements, this site doesn't, just like how some buildings do provide ramps, and **some don't**. That's just the nature of this site, however, and is one of the main reasons why it's so successful. It's a content based system.

Comment: Aify , Actually, public places in the US have to provide ramps, don't they?

Comment: Have to? I wouldn't say have to. I've been to the US, not every public place has a ramp. I do, however, live in Canada, not the US, and even here, not every place has ramps. Also, according to the ADA (Americans with @AgentZebra Disabilities Act), you have the right to request a ramp. IANAL, but from what I can tell it says nothing about old buildings having to put them in if there are no requests. Furthermore, SO isn't just for the US, so if you try to use a US law to justify your request is potentially another straw man.

Comment: @AgentZebra I'm biased as explained. I well accord dyslexia to be accepted as a deficiency, but I don't accept it to excuse laziness. One has to overcome their deficiencies, that's the lesson to be learned (by everyone).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ symptoms of dyslexia are often assumed to be laziness in the minds of others.

Comment: @AgentZebra Well, well, symptoms :-P ... I'm not an idiot, you're not an idiot. Let's talk about the blank metal that's there.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ blank metal? you lost me.

Comment: @AgentZebra No. You've lost me, and [others](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295221/dyslexic-newbies-in-danger-of-serious-downvotes?noredirect=1#comment198099_295221) here.

Comment: *"Dyslexic coders are already at a disadvantage"* - that is certainly the case, and they have my sympathy! But we're trying to build a repository of knowledge and a thousand *"you've misspelled this"* or *"those lines are the wrong way around"* answers are too localised for this model. *"I wonder what kind of features could be developed"* - get a decent IDE, for a start; they can tell you when things are misspelled or (particularly in statically-typed languages) you're calling the wrong thing.

Comment: At this point, it's clear the asker has no intention of this being a good faith question, but is using it for trolling.  It's time to flag and walk away.

Comment: @AgentZebra you are absolutely wrong, but that hasn't stopped you on any other aspect of this so I hold out no hope for your realisation of that. You have my sympathy for this and any other disability, but that doesn't give you a pass on being a jerk, or on being called out for it; that's equality for you.

Comment: @AgentZebra no one is trying to ban dyslexics, you're putting it in everyones mouths. Also you simply can't expect us to accommodate every single disability on the world there are too many. Judging the content alone is completely fair and there are already enough people who deal with it perfectly fine without whining. I have to take my medication, others have to use programs to help them, you have to learn too and not be too lazy, judging on content alone doesn't discriminate.

Comment: I'm all for having dyslexics on this site and having them contribute actively. I however am in favor of banning "woe is me" ranting, which is what this "discussion" is degenerating into. \

Comment: Just as your compiler or IDE cannot take into account your condition, neither should SO.  You need to deal with the facts on the ground, as they are, not how you wish them to be.

Comment: Moderator note: keep your post focused on your discussion. Asking for downvotes is not constructive and should not be part of the post. I've locked this post for a while to ensure that the rollback war over this ends now.

Comment: @AgentZebra Remember: it's all imaginary internet points. In the end, down votes don't mean anything—they're not a chip on your shoulder. Don't stress over it.

Answer (score 29):

I find this whole topic ridiculous, and frankly a little offensive.

A great many people on the network have "disabilities", or better put aren't exactly [neurotypical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurotypical), and we <sub>(or at least I)</sub> don't expect and wouldn't appreciate being treated differently because of that.

Having looked at your posts, dyslexia doesn't seem to be the reason that they aren't well received...

Your heavily downvoted posts come across as conversational, too broad, and not well researched. Further you tend to complain bitterly when ever you receive a downvote which tends to attract more downvotes.

---

Sorry to come down on you so hard, but many have to fight hard to overcome the stigma of their condition. Having someone come out and say "I have condition X, so the rules shouldn't apply to me..." is really frustrating to people who don't want that sort of perception/attention.

Comment: First people have to fight others ignorance of their condition, before they can fight the stigma.

What your really saying is 'shut up already'. 

Dyslexia is often about the way people process and order information.

Comment: `Having looked at your posts, dyslexia doesn't seem to be the reason that they aren't well received` +1

Comment: Josh Caswell :) I think apaul34208 was the first to put words into someones mouth. But anyway, it does seem like you also want to bully me into shutting up instead of addressing the issue presented.

Comment: @AgentZebra I don't expect others to accommodate me, so they usually don't need to be aware of my condition.

Comment: @AgentZebra No, I think you're misunderstanding what is being said.  The point is, here at SO, having a disability is irrelevant for participation.  What you're advocating is essentially, "I have a disability, so users should be more lenient towards me", and you're being called on that.  You're not unique in that fact.  But where others are trying to overcome that, you're falling back on it to use as an excuse for not meeting the standards SO expects.

Comment: Yeah, [my response to your post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295224/) is obviously an attempt to stifle your expression, @AgentZebra. You're too late for the "bullying" conversation: we already [talked about that today](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295215/). If I had wanted to "shut you up", I would have voted to close and delete this question, not answered it.

Comment: @AgentZebra Having a different perspective on the world can become an asset if you develop it. Having a "different way of seeing things" can become your greatest strength or your disability, depending on how you view it and work with it.

Comment: @AgentZebra continuing down your current path could lead to a suspension, you may want to take a break for a few minutes and calm down. Also please make note of the comment above.

Comment: @apaul34208 feel free, if you feel the need to censor a serious, legitimate discussion.

Comment: @AgentZebra and if I see one, I'll be sure not to censor it.

Comment: @AgentZebra I don't have the ability to suspend anyone, and have no desire to censor. Just trying to calm things down before the moderators show up.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think everyone has been heard, there's nothing to be gained from continuing this much further.

Comment: @apaul34208: I'll up that even. Since this discussion has degenerated into a rant, and has been closed, I suggest that delete it as it will serve no benefit for future viewers.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I strongly suspect that it degenerated because of the level of hostility. Some of that  was the OP's fault, but certainly not all of it. Things got way out of hand, but the question shouldn't have been closed and it shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: @apaul34208: did you go through the OP's stackoverflow questions, the ones he linked to? Please do that, go through the edits to the question to see **his** level of hostility. I think that the hostility he's receiving is a direct reflection of that which he is giving out. I'd post the deleted text of his here, but I've been raised to never use such language in public discussion.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's true, but we all could have and probably should have moved to de-escalate the situation rather than stirring the pot.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I agree with apaul here; unnecessary comments and the question itself can be cleaned up when a mod arrives, but I think there's a skeleton of a real thing that was addressed by the answers.

Comment: @AgentZebra I m dyslexic, and have spent much of the last year in wheelchairs and calipers - I would be *horrified* to be treated differently from everyone else... also, anyone could use the tag, how would anyone verify the correct use?

Answer (score 21):

If you're someone who has trouble reading or understanding written material, then I'm afraid that's something you have to take into account when [doing your research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/) before you post your question. You may have to work harder to understand what you're asking about than another person; that sucks, granted.

If your difficulty with written language manifests itself as simple grammatical or spelling hiccups in your post, someone will come along very quickly and fix it up. You're extremely unlikely to get downvotes just for that.

If you're unable to make an understandable post because you have a hard time writing, there's awfully little that strangers over a wire can do to help in this format. Hopefully you can enlist a friend to assist you in person with the posting process.

If you're using your unfortunate natural disadvantage as an excuse to bypass the site's quality expectations, you're in for downvotes, just like anyone else who ignores them.

I won't even get into the issue of ["newbies"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254381/should-we-fork-stack-overflow-for-beginning-programmers) here; it's been done to death.

Comment: Aside: the [dyslexic] tag would be a [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) which we eschew.

Comment: –  Josh Caswell You can eschew all you like, but maybe it's time to bring the meta-tag back :D 

Besides, as I wrote above, dyslexia is not always about spelling, it's often about the way people order information and see a particular issue.

Comment: @AgentZebra Do you intend to actually address any arguments, or just keep stomping your feet and claiming you deserve this tag? You've come to a community you hardly understand and are demanding change. It would benefit you a great deal more to understand the ideals that Stack Overflow is built on and *why* it is so. You can hardly mount an effective argument from a position of ignorance.

Comment: :) I am addressing a serious issue. But I get it, you don't like change, or uppity newbies trying to make Stack Overflow work for them.

Comment: @AgentZebra Or, perhaps, we insist users *understand* why things are the way they are, so they can make *informed* arguments why things should change.  We are receptive to change, when an argument is presented that shows a level of effort and understanding.  What you're doing here is exactly what Chris has characterized it as: stomping your feet and demanding change.  That's never going to make it happen.

Comment: I'm clear on the fact that dyslexia doesn't just mean accidentally swapping letters around, @AgentZebra; my answer specifically leads with "trouble reading or understanding written material".

Comment: @AgentZebra Being  dyslexia myself i well understand your obvious frusration at the aittiude off some off the grammer fascists you have encountered. The effects of dyslexia are very suttile and not very obvious to everybody else. Correcting grammer and spelling mistakes can be very offensive to some people. understanding that due to the way that a dyslexia mind works the phrasing off a question might be presently slighly different to a normal question and people should not be downmarked for it.